# Celery: Task registered but not fired from django

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

**`__init__.py`**

```py
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**`celery.py`**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tax.settings')
app = Celery('tax')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**`settings.py`**

```py
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json', 'json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kathmandu'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('tax.tasks',)
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
```

Python and `Celery` Version:

```
Python 3.8.10
flower==0.9.7
celery==4.3.0
```

**`pip freeze`** command result:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
amqp==2.6.1
apns2==0.7.2
arabic-reshaper==2.1.3
asgiref==3.3.1
asn1crypto==1.5.1
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.3.0
autobahn==21.3.1
Automat==20.2.0
Babel==2.2.0
backcall==0.2.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==4.3.0
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
channels==3.0.3
channels-redis==3.2.0
chardet==4.0.0
click==8.1.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
constantly==15.1.0
coverage==6.2
cryptography==3.4.6
cssselect2==0.6.0
daphne==3.0.1
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.7.1
diff-match-patch==20200713
Django==3.1.7
django-allauth==0.44.0
django-anymail==8.6
django-cachalot==2.3.3
django-cors-headers==3.7.0
django-debug-toolbar==3.2
django-extensions==3.1.1
django-filter==2.4.0
django-grappelli==2.14.3
django-import-export==2.5.0
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-mptt==0.12.0
django-nested-admin==3.3.3
django-phonenumber-field==5.0.0
django-push-notifications==2.0.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-seed==0.3.1
django-summernote==0.8.11.6
django-webpush==0.3.3
djangorestframework==3.12.2
drf-spectacular==0.22.1
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
factory-boy==3.2.1
Faker==9.9.0
flower==0.9.7
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
h2==2.6.2
hiredis==1.1.0
hpack==3.0.0
html5lib==1.1
http-ece==1.1.0
humanize==4.2.3
hyper==0.7.0
hyperframe==3.2.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==2.10
importlib-resources==5.7.1
incremental==21.3.0
inflection==0.5.1
iniconfig==1.1.1
ipdb==0.13.5
ipython==7.21.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.18.0
jsonschema==4.5.1
kombu==4.6.11
lxml==4.8.0
Markdown==3.3.4
MarkupPy==1.14
msgpack==1.0.2
numpy==1.21.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
odfpy==1.4.1
opencv-python==4.5.4.60
openpyxl==3.0.7
oscrypto==1.3.0
packaging==21.3
parso==0.8.1
pdfrw==0.4
pexpect==4.8.0
phonenumbers==8.12.19
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.1.1
pluggy==1.0.0
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.16
ptyprocess==0.7.0
py==1.11.0
py-vapid==1.7.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.8.0
pyHanko==0.13.1
pyhanko-certvalidator==0.19.5
PyJWT==1.7.1
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyparsing==3.0.6
PyPDF2==1.27.12
PyPDF3==1.0.6
pyrsistent==0.18.1
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-cov==3.0.0
pytest-django==4.5.1
pytest-spec==3.2.0
pytest-testdox==2.0.1
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.20.0
python-monkey-business==1.0.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2015.7
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
pywebpush==1.9.4
PyYAML==5.4.1
qrcode==7.3.1
redis==3.5.3
reportlab==3.6.9
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
sentry-sdk==1.5.3
service-identity==18.1.0
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
svglib==1.3.0
sweetify==2.3.1
tablib==3.0.0
text-unidecode==1.3
tinycss2==1.1.1
toml==0.10.2
tomli==1.2.2
toposort==1.7
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.64.0
traitlets==5.0.5
Twisted==21.2.0
txaio==21.2.1
tzdata==2022.1
tzlocal==4.2
uritemplate==4.1.1
uritools==4.0.0
urllib3==1.26.3
vine==1.3.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
xhtml2pdf==0.2.7
xlrd==2.0.1
xlwt==1.3.0
zipp==3.8.0
zope.interface==5.2.0
```

tasks.py

```py
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task
def click_example(event_id):
    print(f'working celery example {event_id}')
```

In `./manage.py shell`:

```py
In [-]: from taxnepal.tasks import click_example

In [-]: click_example.delay('18')
```

The `celery -A tax worker -l info` result:

```
/root/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:800: RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!

Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

    warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
    
    -------------- celery@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-5.4.0-67-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29 2022-07-10 15:14:37
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         taxnepal:0x7f7954c36220
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://127.0.0.1:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
    -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
    . remove_phone_otp
    . send_notification
    . taxnepal.tasks.click_example
    . taxnepal.tasks.generate_event_registree_certificate

[2022-07-10 15:14:37,357: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
[2022-07-10 15:14:37,366: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2022-07-10 15:14:38,388: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2022-07-10 15:14:38,402: WARNING/MainProcess] /root/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
    warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2022-07-10 15:14:38,403: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01 ready.
```

The `celery -A tax beat -l INFO` result:

```
celery beat v4.3.0 (rhubarb) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2022-07-10 15:19:36
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2022-07-10 15:19:36,070: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

Unable to run a task from the shell as well as from Django views. Task hangs until timeout. It works on the development server but not on the production server. What is the issue I have followed all the guides, and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: does redis connection working fine in production?

Comment: @ShishirSubedi Yes it's working fine with active status. Seen through `sudo systemctl status redis`

Comment: Have you tried `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'` in your settings. All other options are having the `CELERY_` prefix

Comment: Maybe you need to define database for the REDIS connection like `redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0` https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html#configuration

Comment: @JanMalte according to https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html `BROKER_URL` is used instead and Redis connection `redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0` does not help to solve issue.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the setting and adjusting the `celery.py` https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: No @JanMalte had not renamed `celery.py`, aslo content is above in question section and it is working in development server but not with `supervisor` deamon.

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly understand where the problem lies as you describe it... When triggering the task from the app, does the message get to the queue? If so, does the message get picked up by the worker? If so, does the worker successfully perform the task? -- What exactly is the behavior you are observing. You should be able to see logs for all this activity and find where it is failing -- if necessary, set log level to debug.

Comment: @sytech gunicorn timeout would occur according to log, had run gunicorn with command `gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock taxnepal.wsgi` via supervisor. I think the worker is not picking up task when triggering from app. Also, scheduled tasks are running properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the following implementation.

In `celery.py`

```
app = Celery('tax', broker=BROKER_URL)


@app.task
def click_example(event_id):
    print(f'working celery example {event_id}')
```

And import the task from the view or from wherever you need to trigger the task.

Reference:

[Distributed Task Queue explained for beginners to Professionals(Part-1)](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-celery-distributed-task-queue-demystified-for-beginners-to-professionals-part-1-b27030912fea)